# Sentiment analysis resources

Tags: references, sentiment-analysis

I need to do a complete presentation about sentiment analysis with its definition, methods, applications and so on.

I would be delighted if you could tell me some resource: links, books, videos, etc.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few links. Hope these can be useful:

1. Datasets ( Helpful for making the model ): 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605702/good-dataset-for-sentiment-analysis
   http://www.sananalytics.com/lab/twitter-sentiment/
   https://inclass.kaggle.com/c/si650winter11/data
   http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/
2. Few lecture slides
   https://lct-master.org/files/MullenSentimentCourseSlides.pdf
   https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/sentiment.pdf
   https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/SentimentAnalysis-and-OpinionMining.pdf
3. Few research papers:
   https://www.ijarcsse.com/docs/papers/Volume_6/6_June2016/V6I6-0245.pdf
   http://www.ijcaonline.org/research/volume133/number9/pradhan-2016-ijca-907977.pdf
   http://ijoer.com/Paper-January-2016/IJOER-JAN-2016-22.pdf
4. Few blogs:
   http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-tutorial-blog
   https://www.quantinsti.com/blog/sentiment-analysis-news-python/

Answer (score -1):

I have just found a great link. I hope you find it helpful too: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2090447914000550 .